# Proof by cases: Prove that if $x$ and $y$ belong to the set of real numbers, then $\max(x, y) + \min(x, y) = x + y$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Question: Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Using a proof by cases, show that $$\max(x, y) + \min(x, y) = x + y.$$

So for this question, I'm not sure how you would apply proof by cases. I think that the $\max$ and $\min$ is confusing me.

Comment: Hint: What if $x \geq y$?  Then what can you say about $\max\{x,y\}$ and $\min\{x,y\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x>y$, then $\max (x,y)=x$ and $\min (x,y)=y$.  So, $$\max (x,y)+\min (x,y)=x+y$$

If $x\le y$, then $\max (x,y)=y$ and $\min (x,y)=x$.  And we have, $$\max (x,y)+\min (x,y)=y+x=x+y$$

Comment: Thank you! I see what max and min mean now. I was just overthinking it.

Comment: You're very welcome.  It's my pleasure.